# The easiest way to change text with flip effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I am looking for simple way to flip text.
For example I have currently "Hello" text in

tag, and I need to flip it to "world", only once , I don't need to flip it back to "Hello", even if sometimes need I don't really need to save previous state. Just pass new text string and it should flip older to newer one.
I know that there are a lot of libraries like https://github.com/daynin/wodry , but for this I need to provide span inside it with specific style, and hardcode all possible flip text strings. I don't need specific part of the text, I need to flip it all at once.
Please suggest the best way to implement this.

Comment: this will help you to make it, http://jsfiddle.net/highwayoflife/ABfMS/1/

Comment: you mean rotate it? from one word to another?

Comment: yes exactly !! One phrase rotate it to another

Answer (score 1):

Without using span, here is an example of what you are trying to achieve
- from Hello to word, without going back ( you can adjust it later to your needs: height, colour, width and the other attributes)

HTML:

```
<div class="flip">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="face front">Hello</div>
        <div class="face back">word</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.flip {
  -webkit-perspective: 300;
   width: 400px;
   height: 200px;
}
.flip .item.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotatex(-180deg);
}
.flip .item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
}
.flip .item .face {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden ;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;
}
.flip .item .front {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.flip .item .back {
  -webkit-transform: rotatex(-180deg);
    background-color: green;
    color: black;

}
```

and a little JS to make it functional:

```
   $('.flip').click(function () {
        $(this).find('.item').addClass('flipped');

    });
```

fiddle url: http://jsfiddle.net/GDdtS/9909/